# Is it possible (and if so, how) to assign the return value of a block to a variable?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Is it possible to assign the return value of a block to a variable?

For example, I know this can be done:

```
NSString *(^sampleBlock)(void) = ^NSString *(void)
{
    return @"sampleString";
};

NSString *string = sampleBlock();
```

But I would like to achieve something like (the following syntax is incorrect):

```
NSString *string = ^NSString *(void)
{
    return @"sampleString";
};
```

I have been looking through several sites explaining block syntax, such as fuckingblocksyntax.com, but this case is not accounted for. 
I know it can be done on a lot of ways, I just want THAT way, for readibility purposes.

Does anyone know if this is actually possible?

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of this? Why can't you just do `NSString *string = @"sampleString";`? What benefit is there in trying to use an inline block like this? Perhaps a real example would be better.

Comment: What's the point of this? I said already, readibility purposes.
Of course it would be easier to do as you suggest, but that's why "sample" comes into place...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course that is possible, but you have to actually execute the block by adding `()` at the end. Otherwise there is not really any return value that you can assign.

```
NSString *string = ^NSString *(void)
{
    return @"sampleString";
}();

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Correctly outputs

> sampleString

Comment: Oh! Of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way. The variable to which you are assigning exists *now*:

```
NSString *string = // ...
```

But the block is just a block: it's a mere function body, a container for code that might or might be called at some future time. Just *when* it (i.e. the code it contains) will be executed, if ever, is completely unknown:

```
^NSString *(void) {
    return @"sampleString";
}
```

So you are trying to take an equals sign and unite, on the left, storage that exists now with, on the right, the running of code ten minutes from now, or a year from now, or never.

This is like some sort of time-warp paradox from a science fiction movie. You're asking the future running of the code to jump through a time-warp and arrive back here in the past and set this variable to something, *now*. This is like asking to meet, *now*, your son when your son is the age that you are *now*.

---

On the other hand, if you do what is suggested in the other answer, namely define the block *and execute it*, then *both* the execution *and* the assignment take place now. The block is merely something we pass through on the way to producing a string that is to be assigned to the variable. And this allows you to initialize a variable by means of several lines of code, inline. In Swift, for example, where functions are first-class citizens, such an idiom is extremely common:

```
let s : String = {
    // ... do stuff here
    return result
}()
```

And Swift even has a feature called *lazy initialization*, which allows the execution of the function and the initialization of the variable to be postponed until such time, if any, when some code actually *asks* for the value of the variable:

```
lazy var s : String = {
    // ... do stuff here
    return result
}()
```